# passing different type of argument to method in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog

Trying to understand the concept of casting.

```
class base;
  local string a;
  function new();
    a = "I am a";
  endfunction
  function void print();
    $display(a);
  endfunction
endclass

class ext extends base;
  local string b;
  function new();
    b = "i am b";
  endfunction
  function void print();
    $display(b);
  endfunction
endclass


 function void printer(base p);
  ext e;
  $cast(e, p);

  e.print();
  p.print();
endfunction

program P;
  base b = new();
  ext e = new();

  initial begin
    printer(b);
  end
endprogram
```

After `printer(b)` executed then I get `cast` and `Null pointer Error` as the below.

I thought that `printer(b)` send `base type` so there is no casting to `printer(base p)` as a base argument. then `$cast(e, p);` down-casts from `base` to `ext`. Why does this casting invalid?

```
xcelium> run
  $cast(e, p);
      |
xmsim: *E,BCLCST (./testbench.sv,24|6): Invalid cast: a value with the class datatype '$unit_0x4ccdf83b::base' cannot be assigned to a class variable with the datatype '$unit_0x4ccdf83b::ext'.
xmsim: *E,TRNULLID: NULL pointer dereference.
          File: ./testbench.sv, line = 17, pos = 13
         Scope: worklib.$unit_0x4ccdf83b::ext::print
          Time: 0 FS + 1
Verilog Stack Trace:
0: function worklib.$unit_0x4ccdf83b::ext::print at ./testbench.sv:17
1: function worklib.$unit_0x4ccdf83b::printer at ./testbench.sv:26
2: initial block in P at ./testbench.sv:36


./testbench.sv:17     $display(b);
xcelium> exit
```

If I ran `printer(b);` after printer(e); then there is no null pointer error but still Invalid case.

Why does casting invalid happen and Null point error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your program, you create two separate objects:

1. a base object containing a member `a` and a method `base::print`.
2. an extended object containing members `a` and `b`, and methods `base::print` and `ext::print`.

You are *never* allowed to make an assignment from a base object to to an extended class variable `e`.

Lets assume you did not declare `b` as a local variable. If SystemVerilog did allow assignments from base object to extended, and you tried to reference `e.b`, the member does not exist.

You are allowed to make assignments in the other direction--from extended object to base class variable. That is what happens when you call `printer(e)`

You need to test the result from `$cast`. It returns 0 if the cast fails to make the assent to `e` leaving it `null`.

```
function void printer(base p);
  ext e;
  if ($cast(e, p))
    e.print();
  p.print();
endfunction
module P;
  base b = new();
  ext e = new();

  initial begin
    printer(b);
    printer(e);
  end
endmodule
```

Note that this prints 3 lines (1 from `printer(b)` and 2 from `printer(e)`)

```
# I am a
# i am b
# I am a
```